# Getting value of hidden input to jQuery

Tags: jquery, hidden-fields

I have a a div section which within it stores a hidden Id value. I am trying to access this in jquery but can't find a way. Could someone point me in the right direction?:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!c.Time_Slot__c == '6:00 AM - 8:00 AM'}" title="6 AM" collapsible="false">
    <div id="firstSlot" class="dragCell">
        <p>{!c.Account__r.Name}</p>
        <p>{!c.Account__r.Zone_Code_formula__c}</p>
        <input type="hidden" value="{!c.Id}" styleClass="inputHidden-1"/>
    </div>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

jQuery:

```
        $(".cell").droppable({
        classes: {
            'ui-droppable-hover': 'highlight'
        },
        drop: handleDropEvent,
        tolerance: "pointer",
        hoverClass: 'highlight',
        drop: function(ev, ui){
            var item = ui.draggable;
            if (!ui.draggable.closest('.dragCell').length) item = item.draggable();
            this.innerHTML = '';
            item.css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(this);
            //console.log(ui.draggable.html());
            $("[id$='saveButton']").attr("disabled", false);
            recordsToProcess.push(ui.draggable.text());
            console.log(recordsToProcess);
            var theValue = ui.draggable.closest('.inputHidden-1');
            var int = ui.draggable.closest('.dragCell').children(":first").toggleClass(".inputHidden-1");
            console.log(theValue); //does not give right value
            console.log(int); //does not give right value
        }
    });
```

Comment: $(".inputHidden-1") doesn't work?

Comment: @JesseMilburn no it doesn't work. doing $(".inputHidden-1").text() returns blank

Comment: ahh, your input isn't an apex element. Change styleClass to class.

Comment: Given that you are using standard HTML elements, I have to agree this question belongs on [so].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input has an apex `styleClass` in the markup, but is an HTML input.

Change this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{!c.Id}" styleClass="inputHidden-1"/>
```

To this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{!c.Id}" class="inputHidden-1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it easy on yourself, give it an Id

```
<input id="myField" type="hidden" value="{!c.Id}" class="inputHidden-1"/>
```

The get the value (not text)

```
$('#myField').val();
```

Comment: I have multiple hidden fields so will need to access dynamically.. thats my main issue

Comment: @saint - Then use the class and a `$.each` with the appropriate selector. The direct answer to your question is to use `.val()` not text. Finding the appropriate selector is not on topic here as there are other SE sites that deal with jQuery/Javascript